# How to change instance type in AutoScalingGroups using API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I need to change EC2 instance type in AutoScalingGroups using API. In my case, I'm using nodejs, but it does not matter.

This link says that the only parameters from description method are available.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-auto-scaling/classes/updateautoscalinggroupcommand.html

> To see which properties have been set, call the DescribeAutoScalingGroups API. To view the scaling policies for an Auto Scaling group, call the DescribePolicies API. If the group has scaling policies, you can update them by calling the PutScalingPolicy API.

But there are no related option:
[image]

Is there any workaround to get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that by creating new [launch configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html) or new version of your [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template.html), and then [update your group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/update-auto-scaling-group.html) to use the new Launch Configuration or Launch Template.